# Go mod tidy removes linters from go.mod

Tags: go, go-modules

In my small project, I have a script that ensures proper code quality by running static code checks, for example, I use [errcheck](https://github.com/kisielk/errcheck) to verify that I handle every error in my code. 
In `dep`, there was a special section for that kind of dependencies, called [required](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/Gopkg.toml.html#required)

> Use this for: linters, generators, and other development tools that:
>
> - Are needed by your project
> - Aren't imported by your project, directly or transitively

For go modules, I can fetch given version of `errcheck` by executing:
`go get github.com/kisielk/errcheck@v1.2.0`

But then, it will be removed from `go.mod` when I execute:
`go mod tidy`. Is it possible to avoid such a situation?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-track-tool-dependencies-for-a-module

Comment: you can just import the errcheck with _ instead of the name, so goimports won't remove the import and go mod tidy should work

Answer (score 5):

In Go modules, there is currently no distinction between “code“, “test”, and “tool” dependencies: a dependency is a dependency.

If you want to record a specific version of a tool, you can add an `import` of that tool's path in a source file that is normally excluded by [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints), such as `// +build tools`.

For example:

```golang
// +build tools

// Package tools records tool dependencies. It cannot actually be compiled.
package tools

import _ "github.com/kisielk/errcheck"
```

(As JimB noted, see http://golang.org/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-track-tool-dependencies-for-a-module for more detail.)